What was the "genocide" that rolled across time and space to kill the Time Lords?
In The Devil's Chord, The Doctor talks about the passing of the Time Lords (again)...
The Time Lords were murdered. Genocide rolled across time and space like a great, big cellular explosion.

Now that sounds somewhat like the events of the Time War, but that was already sorted in past seasons.
But it also doesn't quite match the description of the destruction of Gallifrey during The Timeless Children, either. Life on the planet was destroyed, but there was no mention of it "rolling back and forth through time", and since The Master got away with his Cyber-converted  time lord corpses, one could argue they aren't quite "dead" either.
Have their been any reporting or interviews to clarify this bit of information?  I'm not interested in clever theories or anything, just if it's been fleshed out in any official capacity.

No, It has not.
